# Can't flip pose properly

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

I have a problem with flipping pose, I try to do the same thing as in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YdA-J27YPU). On 3:25, he flips the pose by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. In my case, **it only flips some rotations**, but legs stay in the same place:

[image]

I did everything exactly like in this video.
I've tried to changing from "ZYX Euler" to "Quaternion" (saw this in some other question here) but it didn't helped.

Here is my blend file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37298

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your IK foot bones are not named properly that's why blender doesn't know how to mirror your pose.
Give them IDENTICAL name with **Left** and **Right** prefixes (LeftFootIK, RightFootIK)

[image]